# How to read specific parts from PDF file using iText7?

Tags: c#, itext7

I've just started using iText7 to read certain PDF files which are all the in same format but different text but I'm having trouble reading specific parts.

I've wrote a simple code to read the text:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("tasrit.pdf");
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader);
var page = doc.GetPage(1);
MessageBox.Show(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page));
```

That works fine. However, I need to extract certain parts of my PDF page. This is my page looks like everytime (the text in the boxes will differ in every page but layout of tables are the same):

[image]

I need to extract the text inside the boxes only, without all the header and footer but I haven't found any examples how to do it using iText7.

Comment: Hi, iText 7 has pdf2Data add-on which was developed to extract data from the documents with the similar structure, which looks just like your case. You can try the demo at https://pdf2data.online

Comment: Alternatively you can use iText to parse the instructions creating those lines. From that you can determine areas to which to restrict text extraction.